# Sorting from high to low in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [2] => 9.6
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [497] => 11.666666666667
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [451] => 34
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [459] => 8.8
  )
  [4] => Array (
    [461] => 22.5 
  )
)
```

I have this array.

How can I sort it by number value?

I tried

```php
usort($array, function ($a, $b)
{
    return $a[0] < $b[0];
});
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first... [from the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#refsect1-function.usort-parameters)

> **value_compare_func**
> The comparison function must return an **integer** less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Emphasis on the *"integer"* part.

From PHP 7, you can use the [spaceship operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison) for this.

You need to do some extra work though to address your non-sequential array keys. You can get the *first* value using [`reset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return reset($b) <=> reset($a);
});
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/uni3v (doesn't work in PHP 5.x)

---

The pre PHP 7 version can be achieved with a simple subtraction. For example

```
return reset($b) - reset($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$numbers = [1, 3, 2];

usort($numbers, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a < $b ? 1 : ($a === $b ? 0 : -1);
});

print_r($numbers);
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
```

Comment: For numeric comparisons, you can just use `$b - $a`

Comment: Thanks for the hint.